# How do I delete an entire circular linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, free, circular-reference

I am having a problem with the `free()` function of C's stdlib, of my knowladge this function can only delete a given node of the linked list at a time, how can i use this function to delete an entire circular linked list ?

Do I have to make a pointer pointing to the head of the circular linked list and beguin to free node by node with the care to make each pointer from one node tho the next, be taken to point to NULL before i can free that node ? and if so how do I free the head node ?

Comment: Yes, just walk the chain and delete them one-by-one. And remember where you started.

Answer (score 2):

You could theoretically, re-alloc the whole heap memory of a list and pass it to a free function.
However the most secure way to clean up a linked list is to iterate and free , each node.

This is an example of a destructor function.

```
void destroy_link_list(linked_list_t** link_list)
{
    node_t* head = (*link_list)->start_node;
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        node_t* temp = head->next;
        free(head->data_list);
        head->data_list = NULL;
        free(head);
        head = temp;
    }
    (*link_list)->start_node = NULL;
    free(*link_list);
    *link_list = NULL;
}
```

This linked list looks like this

```
typedef struct node node_t;
struct node
{
    int unique_id;
    node_t* next;
    void* data_list;
};
typedef struct linked_list
{
    int num_nodes;
    node_t* start_node;
}linked_list_t;
```

Comment: Why did you use two ** and not only one, is it not suposed to be only a pointer pointing to the beguinning of the list ?

Comment: It is a pointer you are right.However when you need to have a pointer to free() and set to null.Therefore you have to pass the pointer of this pointer which is a **pointer.

Comment: I don't think I understand, can you explain why this code that i have written does not function ?

Comment: @FelipeDilho I am terribly sorry, just saw this.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how to delete an entire Circular Linked List:

```
    node* clear(node *n){
        if (n->next == head){
            free(n);
            n = NULL;
            return n;
        }
        n->next = clear(n->next);
        free(n);
        n = NULL;
        return n;
    }
```

Call function as:

```
head = clear(head);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why does this not work ?

```
void freePolinomial(Polinomial p){
Polinomial before, after;
after = p -> aft;

do{
before = after;
after = after->aft;
before->aft = NULL;
free(before);
}while(after != NULL && (after->index) != -1);

p=NULL;
after->aft = NULL;
free(after);
}
```

where each node has an index and the head node has -1 as an index.

Comment: There is not an index in a linked list.

Comment: the nodes of my linked list are defined as                                                                            struct Node { float body; int index; struct Node* aft;   };   typedef struct Node* Polinomial;